# Mobile Web development: Differences between XHTML, XHTML-MP, WML and HTML5

Tags: html, mobile, xhtml, wml, xhtml-mp

I am aware of what each of the **mark up languages** does but what I am unsure about is the difference between them as they all seem very similar. I don't mean in terms of **syntax**, I mean the role of each/ benefits etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WML - Wireless Markup Language**

WML was introduced in the late-90's, so its really old in Web years.  Handsets then did not have the processing power and 2G networks then did not have the bandwidth capacity to provide the same user experience that the internet population were used to at the time. Hence, a less rich markup language WML (or Wireless Markup Language) was used instead of HTML. WML is a free and extensible Webdesigner's off-line HTML generation toolkit for Unix, distributed under the GNU General Public License (GPL v2). Based on XML, it is a markup language based on Wireless Application Protocol (WAP). WML cut users off from the conventional HTML Web, leaving only native WAP content and Web-to-WAP proxi-content available to WAP users. But this also made sense considering the limited bandwidth at that time.

**XHTML - Extensible HyperText Markup Language**

It was not until around 2002 and with WAP 2.0 that adopted xHTML as the markup language, better handsets and improved networks (2.5G) that the mobile internet started to become meaningful.

**XHTML-MP - XHTML Mobile Proifle**

XHTML Mobile Profile (abbreviated XHTML MP or XHTML-MP) is a third-party variant of the W3C's XHTML Basic specification. Like XHTML Basic, XHTML was developed for information appliances with limited system resources. These had various versions of 1.1, 1.2 , 1.3 and eventually replaced with XHTML 1.2...

**WML vs XHTML-MP**

The limitations of early Mobile web led to the creation of WML and then XHTML MP. Both WML and XHTML-MP are more limited than XHTML, but they also added new capabilities specific to mobile design. WML and XHTML do not follow the same rules. Today only really old mobile devices are likely to support the WML option. Never phones those made after 2002, all support XHTML-MP.

**HTML5- XHTML5**

So in this vein, this is also referred as XHTML5. With the advent of smart phones, this has gained more traction. HTML5 has both a regular text/html serialization and an XML serialization, which is also known as XHTML5.[56] The language is more compatible with HTML 4 and XHTML 1.x than XHTML 2.0, due to the decision to keep the existing HTML form elements and events model. It adds many new elements not found in XHTML 1.x, however, such as section and aside tags.  Its core aims have been to improve the language with support for the latest multimedia while keeping it easily readable by humans and consistently understood by computers and devices (web browsers, parsers, etc.). HTML5 is intended to subsume not only HTML 4, but also XHTML 1 and DOM Level 2 HTML.

References:

- http://mobpot.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/from-wml-to-html5-a-very-concise-history/
- This [books.google link](http://books.google.com/books?id=dDdg1Lc4LgYC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=xhtml%20vs%20WML%20vs%20HTML5&source=bl&ots=5LaQm8hmKa&sig=9BHU9wvNGco__4wlHsh34r347iw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UJZyU_CDLLLfsATP4oLgDg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=xhtml%20vs%20WML%20vs%20HTML5&f=false)
- Wikipedia Articles